# Prove that $\lim_{x\to0, y\to0}\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

Prove that $\lim_{x\to0, y\to0}\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}=0$

My Try
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Notice that

\begin{align*}
|x|^{3} = |x|\times x^{2} \leq |x|(x^{2} + y^{2}) \Rightarrow \left|\frac{x^{3}}{x^{2} + y^{2}}\right| \leq |x|
\end{align*}
Based on the same procedure, you can prove that
\begin{align*}
|y|^{3} = |y|\times y^{2} \leq |y|(x^{2} + y^{2}) \Rightarrow \left|\frac{y^{3}}{x^{2} + y^{2}}\right| \leq |y|
\end{align*}

Then apply the squeeze theorem.

Can you take from here?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\left|\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq |x|+|y|.$$

Comment: I might have written $|x|+|y| = \|(x,y)\|_1.$ I wouldn't use the letter $x$ to refer both to the first component of the pair and to the pair itself.

Comment: Can one assume that a student doing an exercise of this kind knows about equivalence of norms?